# How to get all the values by referenced Object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following Schemas.

```
var orgSchema = new Schema({
     name    : String,
     email   : String,
     webiste : String
});

var empSchema = new Schema({
     name    : String,
     email   : String,
     role    : String,
     org     : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'org'}
});

var leaveSchema = new Schema({
     emp     : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'emp'},
     from    : Date,
     to      : Date,
     reason  : String
});
```

`empSchema` having `orgSchema` Object and `leaveSchema` has references `empSchema` Object.

I tried myself

if get all the employees in a particular organization, i'm passing `org` object id in `query param`.

```
EmployeeModel.find(org: req.query.org, 
                   null , 
                   {limit: 10 , skip: 0 }, 
                   function(err, employees)(
   .....
   .....
));
```

This is working fine.

And now i'm trying to get all the leaves of employees in a particular organization. 
In the same way i'm passing `org` ObjectId in `query param`.

```
LeaveModel.find(org: req.query.org, 
                null , 
                {limit: 10 , skip: 0 }, 
                function(err, employees)(
   .....
   .....
));
```

But I stucked how to get that? Cause `Leave` referred by `Employee` Object only.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current schema, you can't do it in a single call.
You can do this:

```
var ob={};
if(req.query.to)
       ob.to=req.query.to;
if(req.query.from)
       ob.from=req.query.from;
if(!req.query.emp){
   EmployeeModel.find(org: req.query.org, 
               null , 
               function(err, employees)({

    var empid_arr=employees.map(function(x){return x._id});
    //empid_arr has all _ids of emplyees in the org.
    //now getting all the leaves

    //building a dynamic query

    ob.emp={$in:empid_arr};


    LeaveModel.find(ob, 
            null , 
            {limit: 10 , skip: 0 }, 
            function(err, leaves){
    })
})
}else{
    ob.emp=req.query.emp;
    LeaveModel.find(ob, 
            null , 
            {limit: 10 , skip: 0 }, 
            function(err, leaves){
    })
}
```

You can't achieve this in a single call as `leave` and `org` has no relation in your schema. You have to go through `employees`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I knew that. Let me try

Comment: The closing  `}` curly brace is needed in here `function(x)}`?

Comment: And one more doubt, Also I want to check if the request has optional parameters like `particular_employee`, `from` or `to`. How I can categorised that?

Comment: Are those options in a combination? And do those options need to be queried along with req.query.org?

Comment: Yeah. It may or may not be comes in the query params. But the `org` comes in always.

Comment: @Ranjith check the edit. Added for `to` and `from`. But for particular_employee it should be trivial, if you assume that an employee works in only organisation, directly search like `LeaveModel.find({emp:req.query.particulat_employee}...`

Comment: Saw the edit. It would work but the first query is useless, it is a bit inefficient. You can write an if else and avoid the first query altogether.

Comment: Yeah. You are absolutely correct. Something work around here. Anyway thanks again.